# How do the ransomware viruses perform their encryption?

Tags: filesystems, encryption, virus, ransomware

I know the classic setup ... open a file, click a link -- bam: malicious code execution. *Oh noes!*

But how does that lead to "all my files are suddenly encrypted"?

The operative word here is "suddenly". Applying file- or full-disk-encryption takes a lot of disk- and number crunching, and I don't understand how that happens "immediately". I have theories...

- (A) The virus replaces the disk driver with a "borked" one, so upon reboot it can't read your *not-actually-encrypted* files (other than the ransomware message)

or

- (B) The virus forces a reboot and shows a randomware message, and then runs the encryption task *while the user is reading the message and panicking*.

Now, in situation (A) the simple solution is to read the drive with a different computer, which is evidently ineffective, so that's out. In situation (B), one should (assuming one is not all-out panicking) be able to (a) observe the disk crunching away as the encryption task runs, and (b) salvage (some) files by interrupting the damn task as quickly as possible. But given how quickly these viruses block access to even large amounts of network-attached storage, I doubt this theory as well.

So how *do* viruses encrypt "a lot" of data "immediately"?

***Edit*** due to comments: Ah, so it *is* actually situation (B).

Comment: It doesn't. The computer will restart and show some code that will look like CHKDSK - that's the encryption process. See this [link to "tom's guide"](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/petya-ransomware-attack,news-25389.html) for example (section "A specter is haunting Europe").

Comment: It doesn't do it immediately and they usually filter for various file extensions in order to hit the file users are interested in. This considerably lessens the number of files. In addition it depends on the actual encryption they are using and it's not uncommon to use multiple. Examples include TrueCrypt, which had at least one mode, where you would encrypt a symmetric key you use for fast stream encryption using asymmetric key that you use for protection of the symmetric key.

Comment: According to this [blog](https://blog.barkly.com/how-fast-does-ransomware-encrypt-files) encryption can happen in a matter of seconds. Chimera: 18 seconds
Petya: 27 seconds
TeslaCrypt 4.0: 28 seconds
CTB-Locker: 45 seconds
TeslaCrypt 3.0: 45 seconds
Virlock: 3 minutes 21 seconds
CryptoWall: 16 minutes

Comment: @Cown at 70MB of files with a modern processor and the files on an SSD, I'd consider 18sec even as a long timespan.

Comment: @flolilolilo You are probably right, but most of the ransomwares doesn't even encrypt the whole disk, only important files specified from an extension list, so my guess would still be far less time than a full disk encryption.

Comment: @Cown Sure enough, but consider they want to encrypt all your private stuff: JPEGs (and RAWs) from your two-digit-megapixel cam, your (lossless?) music archive, your movie collection in fullHD,...and just a few PDFs, DOC/RTF-files and perhaps your mail-data (if you use POP3). If those tools are smart, then they'll sort the objects by size and start by the smallest files (probably documents), so if you detect the ransomware attack, at least some damage is already done. But again: the claim that it happens instantly is plainly wrong.

Comment: @flolilolilo True, it depends on how much data and the complexity of it.